# mysqldump Doesn't Work with Full-Text Index?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I often export a mySql db on AWS RDS, via ssh using the command:

```
mysqldump -u myUserName -h myDBname.randomcharacters.us-region.rds.amazonaws.com -p myDBname > myDBname.sql
```

It creates 10 GB sql file, which I then zip and download to my dev system.

Recently I added full-text indexes to this db by running this code in mySQLWorkbench:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD FULLTEXT(field1, field2);
```

Since adding the full-text index, the db continues to run great. Everything works fine in accessing it. But when I export it via `mysqldump`, it quits after exporting about 2 GB of data, and the resulting file causes my sql client to crash when I try to import it on my local dev system.

What could explain this?

Comment: The *contents* of fulltext indexes are neither read nor exported by mysqldump -- the server where the dumpfile is loaded is responsible for building the fulltext index from scratch as the data is loaded.  The only thing adding this index would do is change the table definition in your dump file, which is not going to cause the problems you describe.

Comment: You say mysqldump *"quits after exporting about 2 GB of data"* but mysqldump does not just quit -- this would necessarily be accompanied by an error message from mysqldump if everything hasn't been captured.  What is that error message?  Specifying `--verbose` when creating the dump file might prove useful, and if you aren't aware of this, you also need to know that mysqldump files are human-readable, so utilities like `head` and `tail` and `less` are useful for examining them for hints.  Let us know what you see, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a packet size issue. Adding `--max_allowed_packet=64M` fixed it:

```
mysqldump -u myUserName -h myDBname.randomcharacters.us-region.rds.amazonaws.com -p --max_allowed_packet=64M myDBname > myDBname.sql
```